# Syntax of flat file data sources for Sympa?

Tags: syntax, mailing-list, sympa

The mailinglist software [Sympa](http://www.sympa.org/) provides dynamic membership management via data sources. I want to use a *remote flat file* to add new members. How should that flat file look like? Sympa's documentation seems to omit this. Is it one email address per line?

Comment: Maybe someone could create a "Sympa" tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is 'one email address per line'. Example:

```
foo@gmail.com
bar@yahoo.com
longer@com
```